# User Input in CodeAcademy Java Workspace

Tags: user-input

-HELP! Whenever I run a code involving user input in my Code Academy Java Workspace, I keep getting an error message as shown below:

```
Output:
Enter your user name
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1554)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

---

-My code is shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;                       

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);      

System.out.println("Enter your user name");

String userName = myObj.nextLine();           

System.out.println("The username is: " + userName);
}
}
```